# Download image and update image view without stopping UI thread

Tags: imageview, android

I have an app that connects to a socket server and downloads an image after each launch. What I want to achieve is load default image into ImageView field and provide full app functionality to the user, while the app is downloading image from a server. After download is completed app should automatically replace image in the ImageView.

I have tried to implement `runOnUiThread()`, but it also blocks the UI thread and freezes app for a while.

The only time when I was able not to block the UI was when the user had to interact with the app (press button, touch the screen). In such case downloading of the content takes place in the background thread. Update of the ImageView happens after i.e. pressing the button.

**How can I download an image in the background thread and update it automatically to the ImageView?**

Code snippet of `runOnUiThread()` implementation (method in the activity class):

```
private void updateImageThread() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //This loop blocks a UI thread
                    while(true){
                        bitmapImage = downloadImageThread.getBitmapImage();
                        //Pls note that DownloadImageThread is my implementation of the 
                        //class that connects to the server via socket and downloadsan image.
                        //Method getBitmapImage() returns downloaded image as a bitmap.
                        if (bitmapImage != null){
                            mapImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
                            mapImageView.invalidate();
                            break;
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            });
        }        
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: use image loading libraries such as picasso etc https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **(Asynctask)** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html OR **(Universal Image Loader)** https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: With the AsyncTask I get an error. `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`

Comment: If you see the AsyncTask documentation, it has 4 delegate methods of AsyncTask like onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), onPostExecute() & onProgressUpdate(). In these methods only doInBackground() method is runs on different thread (Non-UI thread) & all others are working main UI thread. I think you are creating/updating views in doInBackground() method so getting above exception.

This is all about asynctask, I think for image downloading/chaching you have to go with UIL (Universal Image Loader) which I mentioned above.

Comment: Async Task is amazing for this job